# How do you get Windows Mobile Device Center to detect a Windows Phone 7 Series emulator?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-phone-7

I'm running some tests and need to be able to get Windows Phone 7 Series emulator synced with an exchange account or local Outlook account via the Device Center.  I'm using the [unlocked](http://www.redmondpie.com/unlock-windows-phone-7-series-9140535/) version of the emulator so that i actually have a reasonable set of software on the phone to work with.  When the emulator launches i expect the Device Center to detect it and start syncing (or prompt me for settings).  This does not happen.  I've tried adjusting the Connection Settings (COM2 and DMA) in the Device Center with no luck.

Is this possible?  Has anyone done it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this will work.

Comment: Yea, i messed with it for a while and pretty much gave up.  Seems like the tools are not quite there...